# Tool for creating a minimal chroot environment

Tags: chroot, debootstrap

I want to run a program in a smallest possible chroot environment with just the binary and necessary shared libraries present. Is there a tool for creating such an environment?

I tried `debootstrap` but it adds loads of unnecessary system files including the dpkg infra.

Comment: Ubuntu runs off of dpkg.  dpkg is used to install dependencies and packages.  You can't *not* have dpkg and core system packages when you call `debootstrap`.  There is no "single binary" and "shared libraries" that don't come with the base Ubuntu operating system and dpkg dependencies.  Even if it were Dockerized.